# Define the Minpts paramter in Local Outlier Factor

Tags: python, detection

I would like to know, how can I find the correct number ok k in the LOF algorithm?
There are many example's code in Python for the K-means, but nothing for LOF.

Thank you

Comment: does this helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138675/choosing-a-k-value-for-local-outlier-factor-lof-detection-analysis?

Comment: https://medium.com/learningdatascience/anomaly-detection-techniques-in-python-50f650c75aaf,

Comment: Nope but thanks. I was trying to implement the first solution but it's not easy

Comment: I can't think of any solution but I guess this can be done: https://stealthbits.com/blog/local-outlier-factor-part-1/.